# Decrypting a file using CryptoJS produces random results

Tags: javascript, encryption, openssl, cryptojs

I have a file that was encrypted using openssl, like this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in /tmp/file.zip -out /tmp/file.zip.enc -pass pass:"abcdefg" -e -base64
```

I want to decrypt that file using CryptoJs. I load the file from a FileReader object, like thus:

```
$("#inputFile").change( function( e )
{
    var files = e.target.files; // FileList object

    var file = files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function( e ){
        var result = e.target.result;
        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(result.split(/\s/).join(''), "abcdefg");

        var string = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify( decrypted );
        console.log( string.substring(0,20) );      
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL( file );
});
```

Every time I reload the page, and load the exact same file, the output in console.log changes. I want to eventually turn the decrypted file into a Blob and return it to the user, but I obviously can't get there until I can decrypt the file correctly first.

Comment: Normally algorithms like AES require a key rather than a passphrase.  If you send in a passphrase, the software is internally converting it to a key.  But there are various ways that conversion could be happening (pbkdf2 and bcrypt are most common).  Are you sure they are doing the conversion the same way?  You might try to first encrypt and decrypt with a key to see if you can get that working, and then later throw in the passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

You should first base 64 decode, then decrypt. Not decrypt, then base 64 encode. Just switching `encrypt` to `decrypt` won't do it if you also encode your ciphertext.